# NSCollectionView won't accept key events

Tags: keydown, first-responder, nscollectionview

I have a window with 3 NSTableViews and 1 NSCollectionView.  The collectionview displays images.  I want to be able to select one of the images and delete it using the keyboard delete key, but I can't get the collectionview to become first responder.  I can select any of the tableviews and override keyDown to accept keyboard input, but that doesn't work with the collectionview.  I've done this elsewhere using makeFirstResponder(_:) to force focus on the collectionview, but in that app the window only had one view.  Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you could select images in collection view or navigate in collection view using arrow keys on keyboard - usually it means that collection view is firstResponder.

So try to enable selection, check if collection view is enabled.

It is also possible that delete key is **Key equivalent**
[read more here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH3-SW10). If so you should override `performKeyEquivalent(with: )` method to receive this type of events

Also the NSCollectionView `keyDown(with: )` method do not pass the key events up the responder chain. To handle such events in it's super view you should override it in collection view by calling `self.nextResponder?.keyDown(with: event)` for such events that you want to handle by yourself.

Answer (score 5):

To expand on Kanstantsin's valid answer...

Irritatingly, NSCollectionView doesn't pass unmodified key events up the responder chain - even if it doesn't directly handle them itself - like the Delete key.

if you need the 'Delete' key to work as a key equivalent for the 'File/Delete' menu item, you simply set it up in interface builder by pressing 'backspace' in the 'Key Equivalent' value for the item , and create a super-class for the NSCollectionView, and override keyDown - like this in Swift 4...

```
    override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    if let ascii = event.characters?.first?.unicodeScalars.first?.value, ascii == NSBackspaceCharacter || ascii == NSDeleteCharacter {
        nextResponder?.keyDown(with: event)
    } else {
        super.keyDown(with: event)
    }
}
```

That way, the menu eventually receives the event, and performs the 'key equivalent' thing.  So you can handle it, eg. in the view controller:

```
@IBAction func delete(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    // ... do whatever
}
```